tcpdump/wireshark show no packets in monitor mode
I'm currently trying to do some tests with the monitor mode, so I set my machine:
$ sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
$ sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager
$ sudo systemctl stop avahi-daemon # According to airmon-ng it was interfering with the interface 
$ sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon
$ airmon-ng check kill
$ airmon-ng start wlp60s0mon

The output for the last command is
PHY    Interface    Driver       Chipset
phy0   wlp60s0mon   ath10k_pci   Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 801.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
(mac80211 monitor mode already enabled for [phy0]wlp60s0mon)

Although it looks ok, I still can't see any packet using tcpdump (No output at all, besides the line saying "listening on...").
In wireshark my interface is detected, but in the Capture/Options/Input window, my interface wlp60s0mon's monitor mode box is not checked, and I can't manually check it. Trying to capture on that interface on wireshark also returns not package at all!
Any ideas on what I could have configured wrong or how to handle it?

Does Turning on monitor mode in the Wireshark documentation help? It has a section about what to try if the "Monitor mode" checkbox is grayed out. Also, are you trying to monitor WLAN network traffic send/to from the machine you are running Wireshark on, or traffic which is not being sent to or from the machine running Wireshark?

I'm trying to monitor WLAN network traffic not being sent to or from the machine. I've read it, but I don't think the problem is on wireshark itself, since tcpdump and airodump also don't give me any output, not even the beacons.
